# PFQueryTableViewController error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

Does new Parse Sdks supports for `PFQueryTableViewController`?

Because I keep getting an error of use of undeclared type `PFQueryTableViewController`. Why so?

`class CustomTableViewCell : PFQueryTableViewController`

Comment: I have the same issue... Can't seem to find a fix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can say Parse SDKs is still supporting for **PFQueryTableViewController** but you encountered this problem because **PFQueryTableViewController.h** header is not including in **Parse.framework** file anymore. So what you can do, in Objective-C Bride header file, beside of importing **Parse/Parse.h**, you should also import **ParseUI/ParseUI.h**. Then the error will go away.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I was searching through the changelogs but could not find a bit of information.